# Form submission with Java and Thymeleaf

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I am creating my first form with Java developing with Sprint Tool Suite on my local machine.  I created an index.html page with a simple form with 3 input fields.  I want to have the form submit to a results.html page which just displays the values entered into the form.  The issue I am having is that when I launch the application, fill in some data, and click the submit button, I get a 404 error.  Also, what I noticed is that when I click on the submit button, the url box of the browser changes to localhost:8080/person.  I expected to see localhost:8080/results.  I thank you in advance for any assistance.

My main application class code is this:

```
package com.baconbuddy;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class BaconBuddyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BaconBuddyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My index.html has the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<title>Home Page</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello world!</h1>

    <form action="#" th:action="@{/person}" th:object="${person}" method="post" >
        <input th:field="*{firstName}" placeholder="First Name" />
        <input th:field="*{lastName}" placeholder="Last Name" />
        <input th:field="*{age}" placeholder="Age" />
        <button >Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My results.html has the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<title>Insert title here</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <p>First Name:
    <span th:text="${person.firstName}"></span>
    </p>
    <br />
    <p>Last Name:
    <span th:text="${person.lastName}"></span>
    </p>
    <br />
    <p>Age:
    <span th:text="${person.age}"></span>
    </p>
    </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

My Person.java file looks like this:

```
package com.baconbuddy.models;

public class Person {

private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private int age;

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

}
```

and my HomeController.java looks like this:

```
package com.baconbuddy.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.baconbuddy.models.Person;

@Controller
@RequestMapping({ "/", "/home" })
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping()
    public String index(Model model) {
       model.addAttribute("person", new Person());

    // The string index will be looked for in src/main/resources/templates
    return "index";
    }

    @PostMapping()
    public String personSubmit(@ModelAttribute Person person) {
    return "results";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have `@{/person}` as your `th:action` in your `<form>` HTML, but your controller isn't mapping a method for it. The `POST` you have mapped right now is mapping to `/` and `/home` (inherited from your class-level `@RequestMapping`). Change your `@PostMapping` or modify your `<form>`, e.g.:

```
@PostMapping("person")
public String personSubmit(@ModelAttribute Person person) {
    return "results";
}
```

Or update your form:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/}" th:object="${person}" method="post" >
```

Comment: Thank you Brian.  I changed the @PostMapping and it worked perfectly.